# Solve differential equation using Laplace Transform and Second Shifting Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Given the IVP:
$$y''+2y'+5y=50t-100$$
$$y(2) = -4$$
$$y'(2)=14$$

Solve the IVP.

I fairly certain that this type of problem requires using the second shifting theorem. First I apply the theorem to get:

$$\widetilde{t} = t-2$$
$$y'(t) = \widetilde{y}(\widetilde{t})$$

But I'm not sure how to proceed, or if this is even relevant. I'm not sure that I understand how to apply the second shifting theorem to this problem at all.

Comment: What is "second shifting theorem" ? Aren't regular methods of soving inhomogeneous linear equations applicable here?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the shifting is so that the initial values will shift to $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$. Since the Laplace transform of the $y'$ and $y''$ are dependent on $y(0)$ and $y'(0)$, this makes solving the problem easier.

The shift gives the equivalent IVP
$$ \overline{y}'' + 2\overline{y}' + \overline{y} = 50\overline{t}, \quad \overline{y}(0) = -4, \quad \overline{y}'(0) = 14$$

The next step is to find $\overline{y}(\overline{t})$ by taking the Laplace transform of the equation, solve for $Y(s)$ then inverse transform back.

The solution to the original equation can be found by shifting back
$$ y(t) = \overline{y}(\overline{t}+2)$$